# Manipulating some values in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, string-concatenation

Let me try to explain to the best of my ability as I am not a Python wizard. I have read with PyPDF2 a PDF table of data regarding covid-19 in Mexico and tokenize it—long story, I tried doing it with tabula but did not get the format I was expecting and I was going to spend more time reformatting the CSV document I have gotten back than analyzing it—and have gotten a list of strings back with len of 16792 which is fine.

Now, the problem I am facing is that I need to format it in the appropriate way by concatenating some (not all) of those strings together so I can create a list of lists with the same length which is 9 columns.

This is an example of how it looks right now, the columns are Case number, State, Locality, Gender, Age, Date when symptoms started, Status, Type of contagion, Date of arrival to Mexico:

```
['1', 'PUEBLA', 'PUEBLA', 'M', '49', '15/03/2020', 'Sospechoso', 'Contacto', 'NA', '2', 'GUERRERO', 'ZONA', 'NORTE', 'M', '29', '15/03/2020', 'Sospechoso', 'Contacto', 'NA', '3', 'BAJA', 'CALIFORNIA', 'TIJUANA', 'F', '34', '14/03/2020', 'Sospechoso', 'Estados', 'Unidos', '08/03/2020', '4', 'CIUDAD', 'DE', 'MÉXICO', 'TLALPAN', 'F', '69', '25/02/2020', 'Sospechoso', 'Italia', '03/03/2020', '5', 'JALISCO', 'CENTRO', 'GUADALAJARA', 'M', '19', '18/03/2020', 'Sospechoso', 'España', '17/03/2020'
```

What I would want is to get certain strings like 'ZONA', 'NORTE' as 'ZONA NORTE' or 'CIUDAD', 'DE', 'MEXICO' as 'CIUDAD DE MEXICO' or 'ESTADOS', 'UNIDOS' as 'ESTADOS UNIDOS'...

I seriously do not know how to tackle this. I have tried, split(), replace(), trying to find the index of each frequency, read all questions about manipulating lists, tried almost all the responses provided... and haven't been able to do it.

Any guidance, will be greatly appreciated. Sorry if this is a very basic question, but I know there has to be a way, I just don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the phrase split is not the same for each row, you have a way to "recognize" it. One way would be if 2 list item that are next to each other have more than 3 letter, then join them.

```
import re
row_list = ['1', 'PUEBLA', 'PUEBLA', 'M', '49', '15/03/2020', 'Sospechoso', 'Contacto', 'NA', '2', 'GUERRERO', 'ZONA', 'NORTE', 'M', '29', '15/03/2020', 'Sospechoso', 'Contacto', 'NA', '3', 'BAJA', 'CALIFORNIA', 'TIJUANA', 'F', '34', '14/03/2020', 'Sospechoso', 'Estados', 'Unidos', '08/03/2020', '4', 'CIUDAD', 'DE', 'MÉXICO', 'TLALPAN', 'F', '69', '25/02/2020', 'Sospechoso', 'Italia', '03/03/2020', '5', 'JALISCO', 'CENTRO', 'GUADALAJARA', 'M', '19', '18/03/2020', 'Sospechoso', 'España', '17/03/2020']
words_longer_than_3 = r'([^\d\W]){3,}'


def is_a_word(text):
    return bool(re.findall(words_longer_than_3, text))


def get_next_item(row_list, i):
    try:
        next_item = row_list[i+1]
    except IndexError:
        return
    return is_a_word(next_item)


for i, item in enumerate(row_list):
    item_is_a_word = is_a_word(row_list[i])
    if not item_is_a_word:
        continue
    next_item_is_a_word = get_next_item(row_list, i)
    while next_item_is_a_word:
        row_list[i] += f' {row_list[i+1]}'
        del row_list[i+1]
        next_item_is_a_word = get_next_item(row_list, i)

print(row_list)
```

result:

```
['1', 'PUEBLA PUEBLA', 'M', '49', '15/03/2020', 'Sospechoso Contacto', 'NA', '2', 'GUERRERO ZONA NORTE', 'M', '29', '15/03/2020', 'Sospechoso Contacto', 'NA', '3', 'BAJA CALIFORNIA TIJUANA', 'F', '34', '14/03/2020', 'Sospechoso Estados Unidos', '08/03/2020', '4', 'CIUDAD', 'DE', 'MÉXICO TLALPAN', 'F', '69', '25/02/2020', 'Sospechoso Italia', '03/03/2020', '5', 'JALISCO CENTRO GUADALAJARA', 'M', '19', '18/03/2020', 'Sospechoso España', '17/03/2020']
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the data you want to process comes from a similar file like this one [here](https://www.gob.mx/cms/uploads/attachment/file/544030/Tabla_casos_sospechosos_COVID-19_2020.03.28.pdf), which contains 2623 rows x 8 columns.

You can load the data from the PDF file using `tabula-py`. You can install it through `pip install tabula-py==1.3.0`. One issue with extracting the table like this is that `tabula-py` can mess up things sometimes. For example, the header of the table was extracted from the PDF file like this:

> "",,,,Identificación Fecha de,
> "",,,,de COVID-19,Fecha del llegada a
> N° Caso,Estado,Sexo,Edad,Inicio de Procedencia por RT-PCR en,México
> "",,,,síntomas,
> "",,,,tiempo real,

*Pretty nasty huh?*

In addition, `tabula-py` could not separate some of the columns, that is writing a comma in the right place so that the output CSV file would be well-parsed. For instance, the line with *número de caso* (case number) 8:

`8,BAJA CALIFORNIA,F,65,13/03/2020 Sospechoso Estados Unidos,08/03/2020`

could be fixed by just replacing " Sospechoso " by ",Sospechoso,". *And* you are lucky becuase this is the only parse issue you will have to deal with for now. Thus, iterating through the lines of the output CSV file and replacing " Sospechoso " by ",Sospechoso," takes care of everything.

Finally, I added an option (`removeaccents`) for removing the accents from the data. This can help you avoid encoding issues in the future. For this you will need unicode: `pip install unidecode`.

Putting everything together, the code that reads the PDF file and converts it to a CSV file and loads it as a `pandas` dataframe is as follows (*You can download the preprocessed CSV file **[here](https://gofile.io/?c=UsLSWC)***):

```
import tabula
from tabula import wrapper
import pandas as pd
import unidecode

"""
1. Adds the header.
2. Skips "corrupted" lines from tabula.
3. Replacing " Sospechoso " for ",Sospechoso," automatically separates
the previous column ("fecha_sintomas") from the next one ("procedencia").
4. Finally, elminiates accents to avoid encoding issues.
"""
def simplePrep( 
                input_path,
                header = [
                            "numero_caso",
                            "estado",
                            "sexo",
                            "edad",
                            "fecha_sintomas",
                            "identification_tiempo_real",
                            "procedencia",
                            "fecha_llegada_mexico"
                        ],
                lookfor = " Sospechoso ",
                replacewith = ",Sospechoso,",
                output_path = "preoprocessed.csv",
                skiprowsupto = 5,
                removeaccents = True
                ):
    fin = open(input_path, "rt")
    fout = open(output_path, "wt")

    fout.write(",".join(header) + "\n")

    count = 0

    for line in fin:
        if count > skiprowsupto - 1:
            if removeaccents:
                fout.write(unidecode.unidecode(line.replace(lookfor, replacewith)))
            else:
                fout.write(line.replace(lookfor, replacewith))

        count += 1
        
    fin.close()
    fout.close()

"""
Reads all the pdf pages specifying that the table spans multiple pages.
multiple_tables = True, otherwise the first row of each page will be missed.
"""
tabula.convert_into(
                        input_path = "data.pdf",
                        output_path = "output.csv",
                        output_format = "csv",
                        pages = 'all',
                        multiple_tables = True
                    )

simplePrep("output.csv", removeaccents = True)

# reads preprocess data set
df = pd.read_csv("preoprocessed.csv", header = 0)

# prints the first 5 samples in the dataframe
print(df.head(5))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for @Chicodelarosa. Tried tabula-py before but as you shown columns and values were completely messed up and I hit a rock solid wall trying to fix it, and pandas was not of much help. That's why I decide to download PDF as a list thinking it was gonna be easier, but still. Your solution was the best!